# Unreachable statement after conditional

Tags: java, unreachable-statement

The following code gives the error: Unreachable statement for `current= current.getmNextNode();`
 How can it be solved?

```
public int indexOf(E element) {

    Node current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (current.getmElement().equals(element)) ;
        {
            return i;
        }
        current = current.getmNextNode();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon between the if statement, and what is supposed to be its body. The way you wrote it, the `return i;` statement will be executed regardless of the result of the condition.

```
public int indexOf(E element) {
  Node current = head;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (current.getmElement().equals(element)) {
      return i;
    }

    current= current.getmNextNode();
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: You mean this should be closed as a typo?

Comment: Thanks, it works now.